# can i insert to db through model.py in django python

Tags: python, django, web, model

can I insert data through `model.py` in django

`model.py`:

```
class details(models.Model):

    team_id = models.AutoField(primary_key = True)
    gbu_id =  models.IntegerField()
    team_name =  models.CharField(max_length=48)
    team_desc = models.TextField()
    updated_time = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.datetime.now())
    status = models.IntegerField(default=1)



    @staticmethod
    def add_team_details():
        details_obj = details()
        details_obj.gbu_id = "2"
        details_obj.team_name = "FTO"
        details_obj.team_desc = "test data"
        details_obj.save()

        return "Success"
```

Comment: I dont know, why you want to do that. But it should work

Comment: it is not working Saeed

Answer (score 0):

Use [model managers](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/db/managers/) instead, for such purposes.

Comment: can i use @classmethod
    def add_team_details(self):
        self.gbu_id = "2"
        self.team_name = "FTO"
        self.team_desc = "test data"
        self.save()